# Why isn't my CSS background image showing on my page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Need some help getting my background image to display on my page. 
I'm having trouble getting it to work and I can't figure out why because to me it seems like I spelled everything correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
'<html>
  <head>
<title>Daniel's Portfolio | Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div class="pageOne">


</div>

    <body>
  <ul class = "nav nav-pills">
<li>
  <a href="#">Daniel Collins</a>
</li>
<li class="pull-right">
  <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
</li>
<li class="pull-right">
  <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
</li>
<li class="pull-right">
  <a href="#">About Me</a>
</li>
</ul>

   </body>
</html>'

CSS

'body{
  background-color: white;
}

.nav-pills{
font-family:Orbitron;
font-size: 1.7em;
background-color: black;
};


.pageOne{
  background: url("../images/mountains.jpg");
};'
```

Comment: Do you have any content in `#pageOne` div? If you don't have any content the height of the `div` will be *0*, so you can't see the background image. Try giving the `#pageOne` some height and check

Comment: I tried that and it still did not respond.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div>` is empty, which means that it is 0px tall (there needs to be some content to force it to "expand").  Try setting the height explicitly in your CSS.

```
.pageOne {
    height: 100px;  /* or whatever height you want */
    background: url("../images/mountains.jpg");
};'
```

Comment: Paige's answer is also useful - your `<div>` should be within your html body.

Answer (score 0):

`.pageOne` is an empty div. Your current content is in your `<body>` tags. If you put the background on your body instead, it would appear. A div shouldn't be outside the body tag anyways. If you leave your div outside of the body, it could render faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this example

You made several mistakes in your html and css

- pageOne is empty put some content in it or you can give height of that div from css
- don't add `;` semicolon like this `.pageOne{};` remain part of css will not execute

Hope this will helps you

```css
body{
  background-color: white;
}

.nav-pills{
font-family:Orbitron;
font-size: 1.7em;
background-color: black;
}


.pageOne{
  background: url("http://hdimages.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/placeholder-image1-600x319.gif");
  background-repeat: none;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<title>Daniel's Portfolio | Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div class="pageOne">
hi
</div>

    <body>
  <ul class = "nav nav-pills">
<li>
  <a href="#">Daniel Collins</a>
</li>
<li class="pull-right">
  <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
</li>
<li class="pull-right">
  <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
</li>
<li class="pull-right">
  <a href="#">About Me</a>
</li>
</ul>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Daniel So please accept answer if you get solution it will helpful to me also :)